# underscoreJS: _.after and _.each; to control async flow

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm looking for _.after function just to play around with it.

```
var renderPoin = _.after(data.models.length, function() {
 console.log( 'siap' );
 require(["ftscroller"], function () {
   $('.dedo').css('width', $li_width);
    var containerElement, scroller;                                     
    containerElement = document.getElementById('poin-nav');                                             
    scroller = new FTScroller(containerElement, {
       scrollbars: false,
       scrollingY: false,
       snapping: true,
       scrollResponseBoundary: 8,
       scrollBoundary: 0
       //contentWidth: $li_width
    });
  });
});


_.each(data.models, function (poin, i) {
  db.transaction(function(trans) {
        trans.executeSql("insert into piezo_point(id, nama, lat, lng) values(?,?,?,?)", [poin.get('id'), poin.get('nama'), poin.get('lat'), poin.get('lng')]);                                      
  }, self.errorCB, function() {
      self.viewList = new Poin({
            model: poin,
            vent: window.vent
  });
  self.$el.find('#poin-nav ul').append(self.viewList.render().el);
  $li_width += parseInt(self.viewList.$el.css('width'));
  if ( (i+1) === data.models.length){                                                       
    renderPoin;
  }
 });    
}, self);
```

however the renderPoin above not executed as expected. What am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's just a typo.
You're not calling the `renderPoin` function because you're missing the `()` brackets in this part of the code:

```
if ( (i+1) === data.models.length){                                                       
    renderPoin;
}
```

**update**
I'm not even going to argue that your code is not even calling the desired function.
Take a look at [the official docs](http://underscorejs.org/#after):

> (_.after)... Creates a version of the **function** that will only be run after first **being called** count times.

If you don't believe the docs either, try this running this simple test in your browser console:

```
var f = _.after(1, function(){});
alert(typeof f); // and be amazed
```

**update #2**
The whole purpose of the `after` function is to leave your *callback triggering* logic behind and just call the function on every loop. The `_.after` function decides when to actually call the function or not, so you might as well lose the `if ( (i+1) === data.models.length){` and replace it with just the function call:

```
_.each(data.models, function (poin, i) {
    db.transaction(function(trans) {
        trans.executeSql("insert into piezo_point(id, nama, lat, lng) values(?,?,?,?)", [poin.get('id'), poin.get('nama'), poin.get('lat'), poin.get('lng')]);                                      
    }, self.errorCB, function() {
        self.viewList = new Poin({
            model: poin,
            vent: window.vent
        });
        self.$el.find('#poin-nav ul').append(self.viewList.render().el);
        $li_width += parseInt(self.viewList.$el.css('width'));     
        // just call it!                                            
        renderPoin();
    });    
}, self);
```

Comment: no it's not a typo, `renderPoin` it's a variable. I copy this from underscoreJS official website

Comment: I'm just trying to help, not to argue. See the update. If you still disagree, I will delete my answer.

Comment: ok no argue. i tried `renderPoin()` but it's still not trigger. And also have check the typeof.. no calling but `undefined`

Comment: you are the man. Thanks a lot. _.after function not so popular make me live in the dark. Thanks again...